# Read value from Kotlin flow and return immediately

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have to read a value from a flow just once and then immediately return it from the function. I have a piece of code like this:

```
fun getValue(): String {
    val flow = getFlow()
    Mainscope().launch {
        flow.collect {
            return it
        }
    }
}
```

But this is giving me an error saying that I cant return from inside collect. I know that ideally I should be returning the flow object itself and then calling collect on the returned flow. But it is not possible, since `getValue()` has already been used in several places by now and I cannot change its signature now.

I have tried using `suspend` and `synchronized` as follows:

```
// call the function like this: runBlocking { print(getValue()) }
suspend fun getValue(): String {
    val flow = getFlow()
    flow.collect {
        return it
    }
}
```

and

```
fun getValue(): String {
    val lock = Any()
    var value: String? = null

    val flow = getFlow()

    MainScope().launch {
        flow.collect {
            synchronized(lock) {
                value = it.toString()
                lock.notify()
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized(lock) {
        while (value == null) lock.wait()
        return value as String
    }
}
```

But in both cases the control never reaches inside `collect`. So I tried putting `collect` inside a new thread:

```
    ...
    val flow = getFlow()

    thread {
        MainScope().launch {
            flow.collect {
                synchronized(lock) {
                    value = it.toString()
                    lock.notify()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized(lock) {
    ...
```

but its still the same. So how do I read the value from the flow in a non-suspending way and return it immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get first value of the flow:

```
fun getFlow() = flowOf("one","two","three")

fun getValue(): String {
    var r = ""
    runBlocking { 
        r = getFlow().firstOrNull()?:"none"
    }    
    return r
}

println(getValue())
//one
```

To get last value of the flow:

```
fun getValue(): String {
    var r = ""
    runBlocking { 
        getFlow().collect {
            r = it
        }
    }    
    return r
}

println(getValue())
//three
```

Comment: This would work, but the problem is that my `getFlow()` looks more like this: `fun getFlow() = flow { while (true) emit("value") }`. The control never reaches inside collect.

Comment: In this case control stucks inside `collect` forever, but `firstOrNull` will work.